# ros2 colcon build

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I write the colcon build function, everything closes including the terminal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402418/ros2-colcon-build/) by [passwd](https://answers.ros.org/users/108118/passwd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-16**:
What can you find in the logs of your ROS workspace? Maybe there will be something

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2022-06-19**:
What is in your workspace? And what platform? I've recently seen this building Moveit2 on Arm64 - and have not yet found the cause.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2022-06-19**:
Digging deeper on my end: it's an out of memory issue. Even restarting a build - that is 75% done, very quickly ends up at 10GB of RAM used (I'm in a virtual machine, 8GB actual ram, 2GB swap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen this happen when running out of system memory - to confirm that is what is happening you can check /var/log/syslog for a recent out of memory termination of your terminal.

A couple possible work arounds:

- add "--executor sequential" to your colcon command to reduce how much is build in parallel
- add more memory if your system is a VM (mine was - bumping from 8gb to 16gb and running sequentially allowed my workspace to build).
- build highly memory consuming packages individually by adding "--package-select package_name" to your colcon command

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2022-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-06-20**:
I had a similar experience with fresh Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS 2 Humble during building [`examples` packages](https://github.com/ros2/examples). When I executed `colcon build --symlink-install`, the terminal crashes and the building stopped after a few seconds. However, I was able to build these packages one by one without any problem